# random intercept, random slope plus intercept, no random slope alone?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, effects

I measured running speed of 70 individual lizards. The lizards were siblings born of 7 mothers, 10 offspring each. The Lizards ran at 3 different temperatures, A, B, and C, where A < B < C, and I recorded how fast they ran.

I want, particularly, to examine whether a given lizard running speed of a lizard increases, is static, or decreases. I want to know if there is consistency (or not) in this effect between the 7 maternal lines.

The models I have now are:

```
# fixed effects only
m1 <- gls(speed ~ (clim + mum)^2, data=mydf, method="ML")

# random intercept model (i.e., one intercept of running speed~temperature per individual, nested within mother, a common slope per all individuals within mother  )
m2 <- lme(speed ~ (temperature + mum)^2, random=~1|LizardID, data=mydf, control = lmeControl(opt = "optim"), method="ML")

# random intercept and slope model (i.e., one slope and one intercept of running speed~temperature per individual, nested within mother  )

m3 <- lme(speed ~ (temperature + mum)^2, random=~1+mum||LizardID, data=mydf, control = lmeControl(opt = "optim"), method="ML")

# uncorrelated random slope and intercept - same as last, but slope and intercept are uncorrelated.
m4 <- lme(speed ~ (temperature + mum)^2, random=~0+mum||LizardID, data=mydf, control = lmeControl(opt = "optim"), method="ML")


# this should tell me which model is the best, using AIC or loglik in combination with the p-value.
anova(m1, m2, m3, m4)
```

My questions are:
Are all of these models and my understanding right?

What I really want to test is random slope among individuals nested within mother. I want to know if a lizard runs faster with hotter temperature, or colder, and in whether there is a consensus.

As I see this set of models, it appears that I can test random intercept alone, and compare it to the random intercept and slope model, but I cannot test random slope alone. Is that true, or is there a model formulation I am missing to test only slope of running speed per individual nested within mother?

And one other question:
Given that I am particularly interested in the questions: a) is the slope different among individuals, and b) is the slope more consistent within mothers than between mothers, do I need this kind of model selection?

Thanks heaps,

Mat.

Comment: Shouldn't `mum` be a random effect (e.g. `(...|mum/LizardID)` in lme4)?

Comment: quite possibly, yes, in which case: `m3 <- lme(speed ~ temperature, random=~1|mum/LizardID, data=mydf, control = lmeControl(opt = "optim"), method="ML")`, I assume?

Comment: When you state that you can compare the random intercept model with one with random intercept and slope why do  you ask whether you can test for random slope? Is that not what that comparison does?

Comment: @mdewey, I thought that including random intercept might consume variability, reducing the power to detect a slope.